# expression to hide tablix based on condition

Tags: ssrs-2008

We need to hide `tablix` in ssrs report based on `boolean` value from `dataset`, currently when we use below expression it picks only first record value which is incorrect.
expression :

```
=IIF(First(Fields!DisplayRecommendations.Value, "Comments") ="True", false, true)
```

is  there any way we could use where condition and get the correct value ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use hidden property of a tablix rather we need to use textbox hidden propery inside tablix.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset returns multiple rows you can summarize it in one at SQL Query level.

```
select count(*) as Display  from Comments
where DisplayRecommendation = 'False'
```

Then in the textbox hidden property check if the dataset result was greater than `1`

```
=Iif(First(Fields!Display.Value, "Comments") > 0,True,False)
```

Note `Comments` dataset will return one value.

Let me know if this was helpful.